# Critical region and power function for hypothesis test

Tags: statistics

Hi all I have a question about Hypothesis test, could you please help me?

If $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$  are independent, where $X_{i}$  is $N(\theta_{i},1)$ , find the critical region and power function for the Most Powerful test of size $\alpha$  of

$H_{0}:\theta_{1}=\cdots=\theta_{n}=0$  against $H_{1}:\theta_{1}=\cdots=\theta_{r}=\frac{1}{2} , \theta_{r+1}=\cdots=\theta_{n}=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What does your book say about this?

Comment: @DilipSarwate It is a question in the problem sheet.

Comment: What do you know about Most Powerful tests?  Surely your book mentions them